# jQuery Datatables server side processing no result return

Tags: php, datatables, server-side

As per title described, i have following code to fetch data in the table using datatables server side processing, but end up has no result is return:

```
    include(mysqli_db.php);

    $request = $_REQUEST;

    $col = array( 
        0  => 'id', 
        1  => 'name', 
        2  => 'phone',
        3  => 'ic_pp_no',
        4  => 'passport_no', 
        5  => 'email',
        6  => 'address1',
        7  => 'address2', 
        8  => 'country',
        9  => 'pp_expiry_date',
        10 => 'created_date'
    );

    $q   = "SELECT * FROM account";
    $sql = $mysqli->query($q);
    $totalData = $sql->num_rows;
    $totalFilter = $totalData;

    $data = array();
    while($row = $sql->fetch_object()){
        $subdata = array();
        $subdata[] = $row->name;
        $subdata[] = $row->phone;
        $subdata[] = $row->ic_pp_no.$row->passport_no;
        $subdata[] = $row->email;
        $subdata[] = $row->address1.$row->address2;
        $subdata[] = $row->country;
        $subdata[] = $row->id;
        $data[] = $subdata;

    }

    $json_data = array(
        'draw'            => intval($request['draw']),   
        'recordsTotal'    => intval($totalData),  
        'recordsFiltered' => intval($totalFilter),
        'data'            => $data
    );

    echo json_encode($json_data);
```

I can see json output with exact num rows return but no data:

> {"draw":0,"recordsTotal":81,"recordsFiltered":81,"data":[]}

thanks.

Comment: You did not add parentheses in `fetch_object`.

Comment: @Atal Prateek, parentheses added, still no result...

Comment: are there any result from `print_r($data)` ? and try put    `$subdata = array();` above `while`

Comment: There is no need to put `$subdata = array();` above `while`. I tried the following code and it works perfectly for me. I would suggest adding error reporting to output of script `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', '1');` or check error_log of php